# Why is the error message empty in the airflow error email?

Tags: python, docker, airflow, dockeroperator

The error appears in the logs but in the email I do not receive the error message in the line "Exception:". Any idea?
I'm using DockerOperator and I've already tried it with tty=True and tty=False.

E-mail:

```
Try 1 out of 1
Exception:
Docker container failed: {'StatusCode': 1}
Log: Link
Host: dba97f6f685a
Mark success: Link
```

Logs:

```
dba97f6f685a
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=my_dag/run_id=manual__2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00/task_id=my_task/attempt=1.log
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {taskinstance.py:1956} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: my_dag.my_task manual__2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {taskinstance.py:1956} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: my_dag.my_task manual__2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {taskinstance.py:2170} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {taskinstance.py:2191} INFO - Executing <Task(DockerOperator): my_task> on 2024-02-13 16:38:33.841697+00:00
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:60} INFO - Started process 908 to run task
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:87} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'my_dag', 'my_task', 'manual__2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00', '--job-id', '2913', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/project_***_dags/***/dags/config/test/test.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpus3spbk2']
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:88} INFO - Job 2913: Subtask my_task
[2024-02-13, 13:38:35 -03] {task_command.py:423} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: my_dag.my_task manual__2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00 [running]> on host dba97f6f685a
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {taskinstance.py:2480} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL='account@company.com' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='Data Engineering' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='my_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='my_task' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2024-02-13T16:38:33.841697+00:00'
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {docker.py:359} INFO - Starting docker container from image crcompanyde.azurecr.io/app_general_python:1.0.0
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {docker.py:429} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app2/test/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise Exception("Sorry, no numbers below zero")
Exception: Sorry, no numbers below zero
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {docker.py:429} INFO - 2024-02-13 16:38:36.280714 Start
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {taskinstance.py:2698} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 433, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 502, in execute
    return self._run_image()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 376, in _run_image
    return self._run_image_with_mounts(self.mounts, add_tmp_variable=False)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 437, in _run_image_with_mounts
    raise DockerContainerFailedException(f"Docker container failed: {result!r}", logs=log_lines)
airflow.providers.docker.exceptions.DockerContainerFailedException: Docker container failed: {'StatusCode': 1}
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {taskinstance.py:1138} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=my_dag, task_id=my_task, execution_date=20240213T163833, start_date=20240213T163835, end_date=20240213T163836
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {crypto.py:82} WARNING - empty cryptography key - values will not be stored encrypted.
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {base.py:83} INFO - Using connection ID 'smtp_default' for task execution.
[2024-02-13, 13:38:36 -03] {email.py:270} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2024-02-13, 13:38:37 -03] {email.py:281} INFO - Sent an alert email to ['account@company.com']
[2024-02-13, 13:38:37 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 2913 for task my_task (Docker container failed: {'StatusCode': 1}; 908)
[2024-02-13, 13:38:37 -03] {local_task_job_runner.py:234} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-02-13, 13:38:37 -03] {taskinstance.py:3280} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I noticed that the error message is "Docker container failed: {'StatusCode': 1}" and the log lines with the error are not displayed, just the log link.

I was able to understand this by analyzing the source code:

```
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 437, in _run_image_with_mounts
    raise DockerContainerFailedException(f"Docker container failed: {result!r}", logs=log_lines)
```

I solved the problem by defining a new email template (environment variable AIRFLOW__EMAIL__HTML_CONTENT_TEMPLATE):

```
Try {{try_number}} out of {{max_tries + 1}}<br>
Exception:<br>{{exception_html}}<br>
Log: <a href="{{ti.log_url}}">Link</a><br>
Host: {{ti.hostname}}<br>
Mark success: <a href="{{ti.mark_success_url}}">Link</a><br>

<br><div style="color: red;">{{'<br>'.join(exception.logs).replace("\n", "<br>")}}</div><br>
```